# Sentiment Analysis Power BI

Tags: powerbi, text-analytics-api

I am trying to run a sentiment analysis using Power BI and Microsoft cognitive text analysis.

This is my code for the query.

```
    (Source as table) as any =>
let
    JsonRecords = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(Source)),
    JsonRequest = "{""documents"": " & JsonRecords & "}",

    JsonContent = Text.ToBinary(JsonRequest, TextEncoding.Ascii),
    Response =
        Web.Contents("https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0",
            [
                Headers = [#"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"= APIKey,
                           #"Content-Type"="application/json", Accept="application/json"],
                Content=JsonContent
            ]),
    JsonResponse = Json.Document(Response,1252)
in
    JsonResponse
```

As far as I'm concerned I did create my parameters correctly. I also double checked my key and API.

I receive this error:

> An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataSource.Error: Web.Contents
>   failed to get contents from
>   'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0'
>   (404): Resource Not Found Details:
>       DataSourceKind=Web
>       DataSourcePath=https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0
>       Url=https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0

[image: Here is a screenshot of what the data looks like if it helps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis) indicates that `POST` request is to a `/sentiment` endpoint, so you should update the URL to `https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment`.